# How can i get only special strings (by condition) from file?

Tags: bash, perl

I have a huge text file with strings of a special format. How can i quickly create another file with only strings corresponding to my condition?

for example, file contents:

```
[2/Nov/2015][rule="myRule"]"GET
   http://uselesssotialnetwork.com/picturewithcat.jpg"
[2/Nov/2015][rule="mySecondRule"]"GET
   http://anotheruselesssotialnetwork.com/picturewithdog.jpg"
[2/Nov/2015][rule="myRule"]"GET
   http://uselesssotialnetwork.com/picturewithzombie.jpg"
```

and i only need string with "myRule" and "cat"?
I think it should be perl, or bash, but it doesn't matter.
Thanks a lot, sorry for noob question.

Comment: `grep "myRule.*cat" <filename>` -- [man grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) -- once you are satisfied with the results of your regular expression, you can use it in Perl as well (e.g. with the `=~` operator or other Perl functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it correct, that each entry is two lines long? Then you can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/myRule/ {N }; /myRule.*cat/ {p}'
```

- the first rule appends the nextline to patternspace when `myRule` matches
- the second rule tries to match `myRule` followed by a `cat` in the patternspace , if found it prints patternspace

Answer (score 1):

If your file is truly huge to the extent that it won't fit in memory (although files up to a few gigabytes are fine in modern computer systems) then the only way is to either change the record separator or to read the lines in pairs

This shows the first way, and assumes that the second line of every pair ends with a double quote followed by a newline

```
perl -ne'BEGIN{$/ = qq{"\n}} print if /myRule/ and /cat/' huge_file.txt
```

and this is the second

```
perl -ne'$_ .= <>; print if /myRule/ and /cat/' huge_file.txt
```

When given your sample data as input, both methods produce this output

```
[2/Nov/2015][rule="myRule"]"GET
   http://uselesssotialnetwork.com/picturewithcat.jpg"
```